# How can I bind view to the end of multiline text in text view inside ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple task at first glance but I'm a little confused now.
I need to add ImageView after the last line of text inside TextView like here:

[image]

But the problem is if I add layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="description_text" for my ImageView I see that:

[image]

My layout now is:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img_info_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="It's a text to fill the TextView with multiline text and see how it works if I need to bind another view after this text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_image"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/real_rewards_description_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So is it possible to add view after end of the text inside TextView regardless of where this text ends. Because the text is dynamical and can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan):

> Span that replaces the text it's attached to with a Drawable that can be aligned with the bottom or with the baseline of the surrounding text.

The alignment of the drawable will be to the baseline of the text or to the bottom of the text. If you want to shift the *ImageSpan* down as shown in your question, then you will need to override the `onDraw()` function or do some other manipulation before the span is applied.

---

Update: Another way to shift the image down is to wrap it in a [SubScriptSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SubscriptSpan) like this:

```
val image = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_info)
val lineHeight = textView.lineHeight
image.updateBounds(bottom = lineHeight, right = lineHeight)
val imageSpan = ImageSpan(image)
val spannable = SpannableString("${textView.text} ")
spannable.setSpan(
    imageSpan, spannable.length - 1, spannable.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
)
spannable.setSpan(SubscriptSpan(),spannable.length - 1, spannable.length,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
textView.text = spannable
```

[image]

Yet another way to do all of this is to use HTML tags (see [HtmlCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat), specifically "<img>" and "<subscript>". You would have to supply an image getter for *HtmlCompat*.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking this is not addressing your question directly, but depending on your purpose you can workaround the problem by appending this unicode symbol https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6c8/index.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a good option. But unfortunatelly I need only this resource for image, it has some difference from the unicode character.

Comment: There is no standard solution to your problem. You will need to adapt something like this com.github.devendroid:ReadMoreOption, it's not trivial.